# How to convert this run time exception into checked exception?

Tags: java, exception

Hi how to convert this run time exception into checked exception this method has to force the class user to handle the exception specified in the method signature. This exceptions are unchecked exception.

```
 public class Exception {

            int a, b, c;

            void set(String data[]) throws NumberFormatException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
                a = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);//convert the string into int. eg1.("12" ---> 12)  eg2.("df23" ---> fail)
                b = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
                c = 0;
            }

            void divide() throws ArithmeticException {
                c = a / b;
            }

            void disp() {
                System.out.println(a + " / " + b + " = " + c);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just *wrap* it into an checked exception applicable in your context

```
throw new Exception(runtimeException);
```

I have used `Exception` but you can use your own `CustomException` which `extends Exception` and wrap the `RuntimeException` into it.

***TIP:***

Also make sure you want to use checked exception for similar scenarios. Runtime exceptions are kept runtime for a reason that the situation ***cannot be recovered*** from. So make sure that the runtime exception that you are wrapping will be helpful as a checked exception. Caller *should be able to derive some value from it*.

Secondly as I told in the TIP that caller will in no way be able to recover from `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, it will not serve any purpose to the caller.

***EDIT:***

I am showing you the demo but I am no way in favor of doing so. Firstly the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` should never be thrown, you should take care that array does not go out of index in your code.

```
void set(String data[]) throws Exception{
     try{

     }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ 
         throw new Exception(ex);
     }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aiobe){
         throw new Exception(aiobe);
     }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `Exception` class extend a checked exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exception in block rather than let it throw up:

```
public class Exception 
{
    int a, b, c;
    void set(String data[]) 
    {
        try 
        {
            a = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            b = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
            c = 0;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {}
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aiofbe)
        {}
        catch(Exception  e)
        {}
    }

    void divide()
    {
        try 
        {
            c = a / b;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {}
        catch(Exception  e)
        {}

    }

    void disp() 
    {        
        System.out.println(a + " / " + b + " = " + c);
    }     
}
```

Comment: I don't want to handle those exception my class user has to handle that exception by using try catch.

Comment: @user3168013 do you have another class user from where you call these methods?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? You want extends your class from RuntimeException, or what? 
If you want catch RuntimeException in this block:

```
void set(String data[]) throws NumberFormatException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
a = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);//convert the string into int. eg1.("12" ---> 12)  eg2.("df23" ---> fail)
b = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
c = 0;
}
```

so use try/catch construction, like that

```
try{
   a = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);//convert the string into int. eg1.("12" ---> 12)  eg2.("df23" ---> fail)
   b = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
   c = 0;
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    throw MyCoolCheckedExceptin(e.getMessage, e);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the RunTime exception if you want to convert it into Checked exception. In the following code snippet if set() is being used, then it will forced user to do checked exception.

```
void set(String data[]) throws Exception  {
        try {
            a = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);//convert the string into int. eg1.("12" ---> 12)  eg2.("df23" ---> fail)
            b = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
            c = 0;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         throw new Exception();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in your own defined `Exception`

```
class MyOwnArithmeticException extends Exception {
    public MyOwnArithmeticException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    //implement other constructors too
}
```

Then change your method to

```
void divide() throws MyOwnArithmeticException {
    try {
        c = a / b;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        throw new MyOwnArithmeticException(e);
    }
}
```